# Two Item get selected in Recyclerview when i click on Linear Layout to change Background

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I searched Lot about this problem but did not Find Exact Solution.My Problem is that if i select layout at some position  to change the background it works fine but at the same time it also change background of other layout.
example if i click on position 0 it also change to postion 9,19
means 0,9,19

here is my code RecyclerAdapter.java

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.myViewHolder> {
  Context mContext;
  private List<randomDatas> mData;
    static int count=0;

    public RecyclerAdapter(Context mContext, List<randomDatas> mData) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = mData;
    }

    @Override
    public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;
        LayoutInflater mInflater=LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        view=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_list,parent,false);
        return new myViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final myViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position).getText());


        //Start of layout onclick Method
        holder.layoutScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final int[] images = new int[]{R.drawable.bg_lime, R.drawable.bg_orange,
                        R.drawable.bg_purple, R.drawable.bg_teal, R.drawable.bg_brown};


                if(count<(images.length-1)) {
                    holder.layoutScreen.setBackgroundResource(images[count]);
                    count++;

                }
                else{
                    holder.layoutScreen.setBackgroundResource(images[count]);
                    count=0;

                }

            }


        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public static class  myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        LinearLayout layoutScreen;
        TextView textView;

        public myViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            layoutScreen=(LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item);
            textView=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.Text_id);


        }
    }


}
```

[See here is Position 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6G7v.png)

[and same thing happen at position 9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYSdu.png)

Here is code of MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Activity mContext;
    ArrayList<randomDatas> rdatas;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.rdatas = (ArrayList<randomDatas>) Data.getData();

        RecyclerView plist = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycle_id);
        plist.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        RecyclerAdapter localPosdataAdapter4 = new RecyclerAdapter(getApplicationContext(),rdatas);
        plist.setAdapter(localPosdataAdapter4);
        setTitle("MainActivity");
    }
}
```

My xml code which is used in to show in Recyclerview

recycler_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="#DCDCDC"
    android:id="@+id/list_item">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="some Text"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/Text_id"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i also tried putting My clickListner on Myviewholder but it do the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View holders are reused which means that once you change the background of a view holder, that background will stay until it is changed back. So, in your example, the view holder for item 0 was reused and became the view holder for item 9. Nothing in your code changed the background back to the default, so it stay at its clicked value.

You need to always set the background of a view holder to either "selected" or "unselected". So, the additional code in `onBindViewHolder()` will look something like this:

```
if (position == [selected position]) {
    holder.layoutScreen.setBackgroundResource([the drawable that is the "selected" background]); 
} else {
    holder.layoutScreen.setBackgroundResource([the drawable that is the "unselected" background]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but can u assist me with Code .That will be very helpful

Comment: thank you very much but one new problem Arise after i scroll down and reach top again color disappear is there any way to preserve the selected color even i scroll.It might be another question as my primary question is answered.thanks

Comment: @bhaskar Same issue. This time, the zero position is selected and its view holder color is set. Now when it scrolls up, the view holder is reused and the color reset. When position zero appears again, its view holder is not set to the selected color. To solve this, record the position of the selected view holder and set the appropriate color in `onBindViewholder()`. In fact, in `onBindViewholder()` you should _always_ set the background color to "selected" or "not selected." I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks will wait for your answer